# Numerically equivalent set differences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying for an exam, one of the practice questions is as follows

> Let $S$ and $T$ be two sets. Prove that if $|S - T| = |T - S|$, then $|T| = |S|$.

The given answer shows that since a bijection exists between $|S-T|$ and $|T-S|$, we prove a bijection exists between $|T|$ and $|S|$ and therefore QED.

Is this really necessary though? Cant I just say

> Let $V = S \cap T$, therefore
>   $S-T = S-V$, $T-S = T-V$, let $w = |V|$, it follows that $|S-T| = |S-V| = |S| - w$,
>       so on for $|T-S|$ and subtract $w$ from both sides and QED

This seems too simple, where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Assume that S AND T means the intersection of S and T, S $\cap$ T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too simple, and wrong. If you want to use *cardinal arithmetic* in a proof then you need to read up on it and understand it.

You assert that |S - V| = |S| - |V|.

For infinite sets subtraction of cardinalities is genrally not defined. You can see why with the following example....

Consider Z the set of integers and N the set of positive integers. 
They have the same cardinality, i.e. |Z| = |N|, but |Z - N| is the set of non-positive integers and its cardinality is the same as N (and Z), so we have |Z - N| = |N| (and  = |Z|). On the other hand N - Z = {} and |N - Z| = 0.

Comment: The actual proof is very short. It relies on the fact that if you can establish bijections between the partitions of two sets (same number of partitions for both) then there is a bijection between the two sets (trivial proof for this). Then S is partitioned {S-T, S$\cap$ T} and T is partitioned {T-S, S$\cap$ T}. Since |S-T| = |T-S| there is a bijection between them, and S$\cap$ T is the same set in both partitions.